# MongoDB Database, order by a field which is a string field but with a number in it

Tags: mongodb, sql-order-by, database

I have a MongoDB and I need to order by a field (id), but this field is a string field with a number in it.

Example:

```
   {
     "_id": ObjectId("4e60f8c2b1638e5479c8ba6f"),
     "id": "3188",
     "type": "P"
   }
```

The id field with value "3188" I need to order on that field as if it's an integer. Has MongoDB got some magic that it can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Magick of mongodb not enough to sort string as integer ;)

So there is only one solution is to make int field from string field and sort on it.

Comment: I was afraid so. Thanks mate!

Comment: @Marc: you are welcome. In mongodb there are a lot of another magick, so, don't get upset ;)

Comment: @AndrewOrsich has anything changed since 2011?

Comment: @rakeshkashyap No, unfortunately. I don't think they are going to implement something like this. Other databases work in the same fashion.